# Youtubeapi error in xml file

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am new in Android Trying to run YouTube Video. When I add YouTubePlayerView in XML file it gives me the error:

> The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
>   because of-
>   "java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context."

My XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.youtubeapi.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My Main Activity class:

```
 package com.example.youtubeapi;

    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
    import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity  implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener  {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1,
                boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

so I have done it and my activity now extends `YouTubeBaseActivity`, but I still got the error for some reason.

Comment: please post the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have added "YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi" in libs folder.

Also in build.gradle file add the following line:

`compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')`

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.materialtheme.youtubetestproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDEDrYVfpbqDgD_EsNlsnsFJhcMP8WYjsM";
    public static final String videoID = "09R8_2nJtjg";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
             return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        /** Start buffering **/
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(videoID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }

    private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {

        }

    };

    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {

        }
    };
}
```